# uninitialised constant Capybara(Nameerror)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

currently i am at chapter 3 of michael hartl's tutorial and i keep running into this problem:

```
C:/Users/HuiHui/sutdweb/spec/spec_helper.rb:82:in `block in <top (required)>': u
ninitialized constant Capybara (NameError)
```

This is my Gemfile.rb:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.1', :require => 'sqlite3'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.3.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

and this is my spec_helper.rb:

```
    # This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause this
# file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, make a
# separate helper file that requires this one and then use it only in the specs
# that actually need it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
# require 'rspec/rails'
# require 'active_support'
# require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'rspec/Rails'
require 'capybara/Rails'
RSpec.configure do |config|

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.

  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed

  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # Enable only the newer, non-monkey-patching expect syntax.
    # For more details, see:
    #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
    expectations.syntax = :expect
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Enable only the newer, non-monkey-patching expect syntax.
    # For more details, see:
    #   - http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
    mocks.syntax = :expect

    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

rails_helper.rb:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

I've installed Capybara through `gem install 'capybara'` as well and it has succeeded...
Can someone please shed some light on this?

**EDIT**:

after adding `require 'capybara/rails'` onto my spec_helper.rb it worked perfectly.
But now it has another problem with `uninitalised constant Rails (Nameerror)`
Please shed some light!

Comment: Is that all of  your `spec_helper.rb`?  Can you verify that you have `require 'capybara/rails'` before the `RSpec.configure` block.

Comment: @vee HI VEE THANK U U JUST SAVED ME FROM A 6 HOUR PAIN AHH. 
bu now it sayd unitialised constant Rails (Nameerror). do u have any idea?

Comment: You probably do not have `require 'rspec/rails'` before `require 'capybara/rails'`.

Comment: @vee Hi i've just added require 'rspec/rails' but there is another issue: uninitialised consttant ActiveSuport::Autoload(Nameerror). Do u hvae any idea?

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that you have quite a few things missing.  Can you update your question with your `spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb` as you have in your code?

Comment: hi @vee ive added the rails_helper.rb!